# REACT & Expressjs: Backend can't 'serve' static frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am making a simple phonebook app as an excercise for a course. I have a backend and a frontend and both work when run separately. By this I mean that POST, GET and PUT work as intended and my frontend sends these requests to the server.

In my course I'm supposed to build the frontends, move the 'build' folder to the root folder of the backend folder and use expressjs to serve them as static files. I get this message 'GET / {} 404 139 - 0.212 ms' or 'GET /index.html {} 404 149 - 0.231 ms'.

It seems that it can't find the frontend. I've deployed my app to Heroku and the backend works there as well and when I run my frontend in dev mode it works with the Heroku backend.

Also when I try to open the index.html file located in 'build/index.html' in Chrome I get these errors in the console (dont't know if means anything though):

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND /P:/static/css/main.e503f880.chunk.css

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND /P:/static/js/1.17677b60.chunk.js

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND /P:/static/js/main.1cb95994.chunk.js

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND /P:/favicon.ico

Any help would be appreciated.

My entire course content is in the same repo so I created a new repo which only has the frontend and the backend for this project. https://github.com/porrasm/phonebook-repo

EDIT1: Tried adding 'static.json' to root folder with this 
`{
    "root": "build",
    "routes": {
        "/**": "index.html"
    }
}`

Comment: you should post a minimal example of your code attempt. This would probably be the file where you're declaring your static directory. I doubt anyone wants to dig through your entire project. It's a big ask.

Comment: @zfrisch Indeed it is :/. I added a file to the root folder 'static.json' which had this content. {
"root": "build",
"routes": {
"/**": "index.html"
}
}

Didn't work.

I was hoping that someone else encountered a similar problem and could provide a solution without looking at the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have Express serve your built React static files such as the JavaScript and CSS, you need to at a basic level use [static()](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). In addition to that you will want to set up a "catch-all" route to serve the `index.html` generated by building the React application using something like [sendFile()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile). This will become exceptionally necessary if you end up using routing within your React application with a library such as `react-router-dom`.

First put the following line after your `app.use(morganSettings)` to tell express which directory in your backend application the static files (Images/CSS/JS) should be served from. In your case it is the `build` folder:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
```

Then **after** you REST routes, add the following line to serve `index.html` when those routes are not hit/executed:

```
app.use('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html')));
```

From what I understand, the `static.json` file is only really needed if you were deploying a standalone React application/SPA. This is not the case as you are really deploying an Express application that is serving the static assets.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Can you fix the second snippet to `... __dirname, 'build'`? (Add a comma). It's not allowing me to edit as it's not more than six characters.

Comment: @Abhijit Added the comma

Answer (score 3):

Was just about to post what Alexander wrote, but in addition, your application is structured oddly.

Simplify the structure like so:

```
├── client
|   ├── build
|   |   ├── css
|   |   |   ├── main.[contenthash:8].css
|   |   |   └── main.[contenthash:8].css.map
|   |   ├── js
|   |   |   ├── main.[hash].js
|   |   |   └── main.[hash].js.map
|   |   ├── media
|   |   |   └── [hash].[ext]
|   |   ├── favicon.ico
|   |   └── index.html
|   |
|   ├── public
|   |   ├── favicon.ico
|   |   └── index.html
|   |
|   └── src
|       ├── components
|       ├── containers
|       ├── images
|       ├── reducers
|       ├── root
|       ├── routes
|       ├── store
|       ├── styles
|       ├── tests
|       ├── types
|       ├── index.js
|       └── setupTests.js
|    
|
├── controllers
├── database
├── env
├── middlewares
├── models
├── routes
├── server
├── services
├── shared
└── app.js (index.js)
```

Then you can run both `server` and `client` by editing your server's `package.json` (`npm run dev` -- for development || `npm start` -- for production):

```
...
"scripts": {
  "start": "NODE_ENV=production node app.js",
  "server": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon app.js",
  "client": "npm start --prefix client",
  "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
},
...
```

Then in `app.js` (index.js):

```
 ...required imports
 ...middlewares
 ...database
 ...shared
 ...services
 ...controllers
 ...routes


 //============================================================//
 /* PRODUCTION CONFIG */
 //============================================================//
 if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
   // Express will serve up production assets
   app.use(express.static("client/build"));

   // Express will serve up the front-end index.html file if it doesn't recognize the route
   app.get("*", (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve("client", "build", "index.html")));
 }

 //============================================================//
 /* CREATE EXPRESS SERVER */
 //============================================================//
 const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001
 app.listen(PORT);
```